# How to generate unique ID=" " on both HTML and jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

HTML:

```
@foreach($permission->childs as $subMenu)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$subMenu -> id}}</td>
                <td> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{$subMenu -> display_name}}</td>
                <td>
                    @if ($subMenu->is_active)
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                                   style="background-color: #f7061a;border-color: #ea2b20;"
                                   value="{{$permission->id}}" name="is_active[]"
                                   @if($subMenu->is_active) checked @endif>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </td>

                <td>
                    @if ($subMenu->is_created)
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$permission->id}}"
                                   name="is_created[]" id="created{{$subMenu->id}}" >
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </td>

                <td>
                    @if ($subMenu->is_edit)
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$permission->id}}"
                                   name="is_edit[]" id="edit1">
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </td>

                <td>
                    @if ($subMenu->is_delete)
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$permission->id}}"
                                   name="is_delete[]">
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </td>
@endforeach
```

jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                if (data[key]["is_created"] === 1) {
                    $('#created').prop("checked", true);
                } else {
                    $('#created').prop("checked", false);
                }
            }
```

now I want to check checkbox. If I selected any role then for that particular role I will fetch data from table with 1 or 0.

I have the array value now I want to send each column value to checked or unchecked  the checkbox according to the data I got.

Comment: You don't need (or event want) a "unique id".  What *do* you want?  A way to identify each data key's checkbox.  You've *chosen* to do that with a unique iD, but that's not a good choice.  Instead, add a `data-key` attribute `data-key="{{$subMenu->id}}"` then use that `$("[data-key=" + key + "]").prop(...`

Comment: If you must go down the id is not an id route, then: `$('#created' + key).prop`.  These assume `key` is the same as `subMenu->id` which isn't clear.

Comment: i manage to solve the problem. thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

IN BLADE **id="created{{$subMenu->id}}"** , ITS UNIQUE
IN QUERY USE **$('#element_id'+id)**  & **id** WILL BE PASSED BY A FUNCTION